# Verifying that async task run with robolectric 3

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a method that starts couple of async tasks on background thread:

```
public void fetchSome() {
    new SomeTask1().execute();
    new SomeTask2().execute();
    new SomeTask3().execute();
}
```

How can I test that these three tasks are executed with [Robolectric 3.0](http://robolectric.org).

Comment: Just curious, what am I missing for receiving the downvote? I'll improve it.

Comment: What do you want to test here? You started three AsyncTasks? Their result? One more question - why the method is package scope?

Comment: I want to test these three tasks are executed. I updated the question with more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before I would warn you that `AsyncTask` are not good solution for performing background operations. Take a look to talks in internet what is so bad with `AsyncTask`.

As for me you're trying to test too many things. I would split it.

1. Test that your code is starting async tasks:

   - Write a Factory class which will instantiate async tasks for you
   - Mock factory in test and return mocks for tasks
   - Check that execute for task happened
2. Test that your tasks are doing right job:

   - Write test for every async task class
   - mock dependencies and check that tasks are interacting with outside world correctly
3. Test that your tasks update UI with result:

   - Introduce listeners
   - Mock them and pass to async tasks
   - Check that sync tasks calls them during final own lifecycle
   - Make UI implement listeners contract
   - Call in UI test listener methods
   - Check that it is updated correctly with results

Hope it helps!